# drobo/rsync create weird root folder

Tags: rsync, drobo

Running rsync from a drobo to fetch remote files, rsync create a wierdly named folder "_2X68O~Y" which contains the fetched files and folders. Under sh the folder has an empty name.

the commandine, run via a .sh script:

> /mnt/DroboNAS/Shares/DroboApps/rsync/rsync -av --delete-during --exclude Recycle\ Bin rsync://192.168.26.2/BATI /mnt/DroboNAS/Shares/Backup/mtl/shares/montreal_bati/

so I'm getting `/mnt/DroboNAS/Shares/Backup/mtl/shares/montreal_bati/_2X68O~Y/[files / folders]`

`rsync  version 3.0.7  protocol version 30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same script on a FreeNAS box (written in komodo edit) and I had the same issue. I think it's a charset issue. I deleted it (on the freenas box) and rewrote it using putty/nano and it works.